# Returning more than one field from Django model

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How would one go about returning more than one field from a Django model declaration?

For instance: I have defined:

```
class C_I(models.Model):
    c_id = models.CharField('c_id', max_length=12)
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)
```

which I can use, when called in a views.py function to return

```
    {{ c_index }}

        {% for c in c_index %}

            <div class='c-index-item' c-id=''>

                <p>{{ c.name }}</p>

            </div>

        {% endfor %}
```

from a template. This is being called in my views.py like so:

```
c_index = C_I.objects.all()

t = get_template('index.html')

c  = Context({'c_index': c_index})

html = t.render(c)
```

How would I also include the c_id defined in the model above, so that I can include {{c.name}} and {{c.c_id}} in my template? When I remove the **str** method, I appear to get all of the results, however, it just returns blank entries in the template and will not let me reference the individual components of the object.

Comment: I have tried return '%s %s' % (self.name, self.c_id) and also return '%s, %s' % (self.name, self.c_id)

Comment: You are passing a list of `Calendar` objects from the view function to the template to render, so for individual instances you should be able to access any attribute that the `Calendar` model defines (without defining a `__str__` method). Try changing the content of the `<p>` tag to `{{ c.c_id }}, {{ c.name }}`. Does that result in any errors when you access the view?

Comment: It doesn't result in an error, but it is blank. Furthermore, when I print c_index, which is defined just as it is above, I only get the name and the c_id back, but if I comment out the __str__ method, I get an array of calendar items

Comment: What's your code for passing `c_index` to the template? I.e., can you please add the code of the view function responsible for rendering the template to your post?

Comment: I've added it to the body of the question

Comment: Reasoning for the downvote maybe?

Comment: I didn't downvote you. I am getting a bit confused though, about what you are trying to print or show where. Can you include a small screenshot of what you are seeing when you are accessing your view in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is fine. Your template should be:

```
    {% for c in c_index %}
        <div class='c-index-item' c-id='{{ c.c_id }}'>
            <p>{{ c.name }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```